# How do I create a Task Scheduler in Ubuntu?

Tags: system-settings

I am not able to create a Task Scheduler on Ubuntu. How do I do that?

Comment: What "Tasks" do you wish to "schedule"? Have you typed the `man  -a crontab` command?

Answer (score 5):

For instance with [gnome task scheduler](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-schedule/):

[image]

This basically is a GUI for creating crontab rules.

---

From command line you can do this yourself by editing the crontab file with

```
sudo /etc/crontab
```

- [Quick reference guide](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)
- Or in an image:

[image]

---

Or in "cron" with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Works basically the same as the previous one but does not have a "user" on the line.

Comment: Didn't know about this...  Installed! (and upvoted)